# Facebook Application made using cakephp is very slow

Tags: cakephp, facebook

I have created a facebook application in cakephp. This application is very very slow as compared to other apps.

What shall I do to increase it's speed? Please suggest something as this issue is driving me nuts.

Thanks

Comment: I think we're going to need more information.  Is there a specific part of it that is slow?  Can you post some code?

Comment: cakephp is generally very slow - if you find a overall solution to this let me know ;)

Comment: do you have any proof of your saying, I mean to say any links or resources that made you think so.

Comment: hi inkedm,

no the complete app is slow.

Comment: I've used CakePHP for small apps, and I find it to be fast enough.  It would help if you could post, say, your slowest controller/model/view to see if there's an obvious problem.

Answer (score 3):

we use (soon used) cakephp as well for fb apps

cakephp seems just to be slow.

anyway maybe this helps:

my facebook specific tips and learnings:

- reduce all api calls to the needed minimum

  - use fbml whereever you can
- batch all api calls that are batchable

  - batch all fql api calls
- cache the output of each api call you will need at the next page

  - cache it at memcache or do a ramdisk for cache::file

generic must-do's

- use memcache
- do not hit database if not 100% needed
- do not hit the filesystem
- do everything you can do async (crondispatcher)
- use javascript effects to simulate quick response

Comment: what is meant by "javascript effects to simulate quick response."?

Can you please throw some light on this technique.

Comment: I think he's talking about asyncronous requests, i.e. Ajax

Comment: basically yes ajax - if you submit a form which adds content to a form dont wait for the response of the server - display it as added content
if you delete content from somewhere send the response to the server and instantly fadeout the element etc

Comment: so it means you are able to use ajax in facebook apps..? I have posted another problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186855/jquerys-ajax-not-working-in-facebook-apps where ajax was not working in the same application.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set debug to '0' in core.php?  If not, that will give you a huge speed boost.

Comment: thanks for your help, as suggested by you I did it but there's no speed gain at all :-(

Answer (score 1):

It generally is not the server side code that's slow. I doubt CakePHP is slowing you down. It's the DB access, the Facebook API calls and the HTML rendering ([Use YSlow!](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)) that account for 80-90% of the time spent loading an application.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I think cakephp is slow because when I set the debug mode "on" I was shocked to see the number of queries it runs just to show records from a single table..

Comment: Then it is a DB access problem no? Have you tried profiling the server side code? Making multiple queries doesn't necessarily slow things down. Especially if your database doesn't have a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

This book by Matt Curry might be helpful:

http://www.pseudocoder.com/Super_Awesome_Advanced_CakePHP_Tips.pdf

@ Page 54 -> "Make Your Cake App Fast"

And as conserning this you mentioned earlier:

> "but I think cakephp is slow because when I set the debug mode "on" I was shocked to see the number of queries it runs just to show records from a single table.. "

Try setting this to every model:

```
var $recursive = -1;
```

Then use recursive queries only when needed. And some of the queries you see when using debug >0 is because Cake is updating model cache. (Like Karel already mentioned.)

Answer (score 0):

(replying here for the sake of search results ending up here)

If you see a massive amount of DB queries done, you probably have caching turned off so CakePHP tries to get a full description of the database tables every time a page runs. Turn that on, make sure your caches are actually written to disk (or memcache or whatever you use).

That + limiting the amount of API calls to Facebook should speed up your application by a lot already.