# jquery ajax request works only in firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

I have the following html, alert works only in mozilla firefox when I click the button.Why?

```
<html>
       <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
          $.ajax({url:"https://graph.facebook.com/1524623057/", 
          success:function(){
           alert(1);
          }});
        });});
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <button>send request</button>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery's ajax not working in facebook apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186855/jquerys-ajax-not-working-in-facebook-apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result from facebook isn't proper json, as it has line breaks and tabs - also, it's served as text/javascript.

Facebook supports jsonp, however, so you could do this instead:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/1524623057/',
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'jsonp'
}).done( function( data ){
  // the data!
});
```

This will basically tack on the ?callback=jQuery23423234234 or whatever random id is generated to facebook, returning a function that can be called.

If you want to parse it yourself, do:

Tell `$.ajax` to use type 'text', e.g.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/1524623057/',
  dataType: 'text'
})
```

and then clean it up. Here's an answer on SO about cleaning up that kind of js, so you can use `$.parseJSON` instead of having to throw it in a new function or eval'ing it. [Converting multiline, indented json to single line using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791356/converting-multiline-indented-json-to-single-line-using-javascript)

That way, you can `var data = $.parseJSON( cleanedUpJsonFromFacebook )` and access the object properties.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that request returns a JSON data type. The code is complaining about a colon when it receives the result and doesn't recognize the JSON.

Try this:

```
$.ajax("https://graph.facebook.com/1524623057/",
    { 
        success:function(){
            alert(1);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }
);
```

Also, the success callback takes a response parameter that you can use to inspect the JSON when you get it back.

Check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: the data returned from fb isn't valid json, both in it's type ( text/javascript) and format (valid json doesn't contain new lines or tabs chars between keys and values)

Comment: I think their script does `var result = (new Function('return '+data)());`