# Facebook Page JSON Feed failing with jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, json, jsonp

I'd like to pull the feed from a public facebook wall without using the graph api or server side code. I'm using jQuery and a url from a link labeled "Get Updates via RSS" for my example which is Nike's fan page. I'm getting an uncaught syntaxerror with the first ":" however. It makes me wonder if jsonp is even supported by facebook. Here's the code that breaks.

http://jsfiddle.net/9PQqa/

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: "http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=15087023444&format=json&callback=?",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data){
    document.write('success');
    document.write(data.toSource());
},
error: function(){
    document.write('error');
}
```

});

I'm new at a lot of ajaxy stuff, so any help is welcome.

Comment: hv u got the solution man?

Answer (score 0):

That url is returned as `text/javascript` - see [jquery ajax request works only in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391767/jquery-ajax-request-works-only-in-firefox/8391922#8391922) for more information.

I also updated that answer with a more flexible solution: using jsonp

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "https://graph.facebook.com/15087023444/feed",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  type: 'get',
  success: function(data){
    console.log( 'success' );
    console.dir( data );
  },
  error: function(){
    console.log( 'error!' );
  }
});
```

Comment: My request returns Content-type:application/json, so I'm not sure I follow. I agree there may some odd characters in there (i.e. tabs and line breaks) that cause the syntax error but the example you linked to doesn't seem to solve this issue for me. I either get a crossdomain issue or the same syntax error. Also, why did you leave out the "format=json" from the query string?

Comment: By switching to jsonp, you avoid the cross-domain issues as well as not parsing as json but creating the object via the jsonp callback, hence, not telling facebook to format as json.